# Python Building App

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

So here is the problem:
I am building an app in pyqt:

1. frame1.py

   ```
   from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
   import runpy, sys

   class LoginFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):

       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.logFrameSetup(self)

       def logFrameSetup(self, GuiWin):
               GuiWin.setWindowTitle('GuiWin')
               GuiWin.resize(450, 215)

               self.pushbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Go To', GuiWin)
               self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.change)

       def change(self):
           try:
               runpy.run_path('frame2.py', run_name="__main__")
           except:
               pass
           finally:
               self.close()


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
       ex = LoginFrame()
       ex.show()
       x = app.exec_()
       sys.exit(x)
   ```
2. frame2.py

   ```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    import sys
    class MainTradingPlatform(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

       self.setupFrame(self)

    def setupFrame(self, frame2):
        frame2.setWindowTitle('2frame')
        frame2.resize(1200, 1000)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = MainTradingPlatform()
   ex.show()
   x = app.exec_()
   sys.exit(x)
   ```

Now this works almost perfect, but when i close frame2.py, the process in background is still in progress/running.
What I want to achieve is that by closing frame2.py, process is finished with exit code. (terminated)

ps: after calling frame2.py, i would also like to terminate frame1.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my response.

Comment: Call `sys.exit` in your code by the end of the program, or even `multiprocessing.current_process().terminate`

Comment: What process? How do you start it? Can you show some code?

Comment: Question is updated. Thank you for your respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute the code with runpy, the process is separated from the initial application, an option to close the second application is to overwrite the closeEvent method.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
class MainTradingPlatform(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupFrame(self)

    def setupFrame(self, frame2):
        frame2.setWindowTitle('2frame')
        frame2.resize(1200, 1000)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainTradingPlatform()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. I've also learned a lot through reading documents, but sometimes the gap between making it right is soooo small :) thank you again.